# spacy how do I make a matcher which is noun-noun without white space within it?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, spacy

I tried to make a matcher which could detect words like

'all-purpose'

I was trying to make a pattern like

`pattern=[{'POS':'NOUN'}, {'ORTH':'-'},{'POS':'NOUN'}]`

However, I realized that it only find the matches like

'all - purpose' with white space between tokens instead of 'all-purpose'.

How could I make a matcher like this?
It has to be a generalized pattern like noun-noun instead of
specific words like 'Barak Obama' as in the example in spacy documentation

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to match? Using `en_core_web_sm`, "all-purpose" is three tokens and `all` has the ADV POS tag for me. So that might be the issue with your match pattern. If you just want hyphenated words this might be a better match:

```
pattern = [{'IS_ALPHA': True}, {'ORTH':'-'}, {'IS_ALPHA': True}]
```

More generally, you are correct that your pattern will only match three tokens, though that doesn't require white space - it depends on how the tokenizer works. For example, `that's` has no spaces but is two tokens.

If you are finding hyphenated words that occur as one token and want to match them, you can use [regular expressions in Matcher rules](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex). Here's an example ofhow that would work from the docs:

```
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "deff?in[ia]tely"}}]
```

In your case it could just look like this:

```
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "-"}}]
```